# How to install homebrew on Lion

Tags: macos, homebrew

I tried install homebrew on my Lion, and got this

```
remote: Counting objects: 77394, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (37271/37271), done.
remote: Total 77394 (delta 52745), reused 61413 (delta 39308)
Receiving objects: 100% (77394/77394), 10.96 MiB | 1.87 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (52745/52745), done.
From https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
error: Untracked working tree file '.gitignore' would be overwritten by merge.
Failed during: git pull origin master
```

What is this? How to get this working?

Comment: What install method are you using? `ruby <(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)` as recommended on the [Homebrew site](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/)?

Comment: I runned `brew doctor` and got `Your system is raring to brew.`...seems like it's ok now

Comment: Okay good. It would be helpful for others who might be having the same problem if you wrote out what you did as an answer to this question.

Comment: I just runned it again...lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your terminal app and paste in the following code:

`ruby <(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)`